# Avoiding GTM and other unused js with Firebase Analytics

Tags: javascript, firebase, webpack, seo, google-tag-manager

I am using Firebase in my project and importing Firebase libraries separately. In an attempt to reduce the load speeds, I ran my site on Google's PageSpeed Insights and found out that there are a number of js code coming with Firebase that I do not use and want to get rid off. The below screenshot can give you an idea.

[image]

However, I could not find a way to achieve this despite checking this for a week now. Any help would be appreciated.